# Rails server works fine on computer, but I can't access it over the network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking, server

I have a rails server setup on a CentOS with a static ip that's accessible to the outside network.

If I go to http://my.ip.address on that machine, it works fine and I can see my rails server and the access is logged in /var/log/httpd/access_log

However, if I do the same thing on another computer, the connection times out and I don't see the access in the access_log.

netstat shows that httpd is listening on port 80, so as far as I can tell, everything seems to be working fine.

What else could be blocking this connection if it's not the network blocking the access?

Comment: I think it might be the firewall policy that CentOS ships with. See this http://www.binarytides.com/open-http-port-iptables-centos/

Comment: This was the problem, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to start the rails server with `-b 0.0.0.0` (older versions do not require this).

Comment: Ah, you remind me that! And also verify if the httpd listens on 0.0.0.0:80.

Answer (score 0):

Aetherus was correct.  CentOS was blocking port 80 by default.  I followed the guide in his link and was able to solve the problem.

For future users, these are the commands that fixed the problem:

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

The first line adds a line (at line position 5) to your iptables configuration that accepts traffic on port 80. The second line saves the configuration so it's persistent through reboots.

Note that if you have any iptables configuration other than default, you may need to adjust the command so it inserts at a line other than position 5.  In this case, position 5 is used because it is above the last REJECT filter that is at line number 5 by default.